# impact of removing "+:d" in verilog timing section

Tags: verilog, vlsi

I would like to start with the simple example of a flop, and my concentration lies in the specify section , so please ignore the functionality part

```
module flop (clk,d,o);

...... //Functionality

    specify //Timing section starts

        posedge clk => (q [B]+:d[/B]) = 0;

    endspecify
endmodule
```

So from the above example, I need to know the exact significance of this  part: `+:d`. I completely understand that it is the data path.

What would be the impact if i would remove it?

And also backannotation sdf file shows only `clk=>q` path with delays annotated, but doesn't show any datapath (d) related to that statement. So does that mean it is of no use?

Comment: Google 'edge sensitive paths'.  http://hellovlsi.blogspot.in/2014/06/edge-sensitive-paths-conditional-path.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

A delay between a source and a destination pin of a module is known as **module path delay**. These delays are modeled using `specify` blocks.

There can be two types of delay specification in `specify` block: Parallel Connection and Full connection.

In Parallel connection, each bit in source field connects individually with its destination bit. As shown in below image:

[image: Parallel connection]

**The syntax is :**

```
(source_bit => destination_bit) = delay_value
```

While in Full Connection, each bit in source field connects every bit in the destination field. As shown in below image:

[image: Full connection]

**The syntax is:**

```
(source_bit *> destination_bit) = delay_value
```

In your case, `posedge clk => (q [B]+:d[/B]) = 0;` This is a **parallel** type of delay connection. This means whenever a `posedge` of clock signal arrives, the value of `q[B]` shall change with a delay of **0units**.

Since there is **no** demarcation with respect to **rise and fall times**, the delay applies **equally** to **both** rising and falling edge of `q[B]`.

**The polarity operator** (`+:`) describes if data passing from the source to the output is inverted (-) or not inverted (+). The polarity operator is used by **timing analysis tools** and is **ignored by the simulator**.

**Positive polarity** (`+:`) : This is used when a **rise** at the **source** causes a **rise transition** at the **destination** and a fall transition at the source causes the fall transition at the destination.

**Negative Polarity** (`-:`) : This is used when a **rise** transition at the **source** causes **fall** **transition** at the **destination**, and a fall transition at the source causes a rise transition at the destination.

But, modern timing analysis tools rely on their own library, I guess. So, it might be safe to ignore that operator. Somewhat information on polarity operator is available at [this](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00014.htm) link.

Answer (score 1):

This was for static timing analysis tools that used Verilog as the library source description. AFAIK, static timing analysis tools that use Verilog as their complete source no longer exist (i.e. Veritime) and current tools use their own library source descriptions. So you can ignore it.